# Oracle Connector SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to setup an oracle connector in SSIS  via visual studio 2017 and receive this error.

[image]

However I am able to connect via the windows ODBC

[image]

[image]

My tnsnames.ora file is correct. There is another user that is able to use the oracle connector via SSDT and connect successfully.

Any tips please?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is a 32 bit application so ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) is the wrong one to test in.

Comment: Thanks It also works in ODBC 32 bit. I have been doing some reading and it seems that at a certain point for VS 2017 the oracle connector does not work? So I should go back to an earlier version?